# Transfer data from device A to device B through NFC without NFC tags

Tags: android, swift, core-nfc

I'm planning to make an app where we can mark the attendance, so device A will be used to mark attendance as NFC, so is it possible or I must need an NFC TAG to perform this operation.

I'll be thankful if someone can help me or give me a link if he worked before on this, i searched but most of the people are saying we need a tag

Comment: Your tags for this question include one for Android and two for iOS. I recommend that you scope your question to a single operating system.

Comment: I need a solution either in android or iOS or in both, so I could work accordingly if it'll be doable in one platform then we'll make one app otherwise both